# Как изменить позицию кнопки в CSS

Tags: css

Нужно переместить кнопку на другую строну, как в изображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
button {
    border-color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20pt;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: #cc3354;
    padding: 10;
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
    height: 42px;
    width: 140px;
}
```

Comment: зависит от `display`... например так: `float:right` или `margin-left:auto` или `text-align:right`

Comment: добавьте в снипете **воспроизводимый** минимальный код, и я точнее отпишу в ответе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.block {
  width:100%;
}

.fr {
  float:right;
}

.fl{
  float:left;
}

.ma {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.mt {
  text-align: right;
}

.d-flex {
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"><button class="fr">BTN</button></div>
<br>
<div class="block d-flex"><button class="ma">BTN</button></div>
<br>
<div class="block mt"><button>BTN</button></div>
```